# Joomla Virtuemar 2.x

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

im traying to show in the products detail page, the list of the other products by the same Manufacturer. I mean, if you are in a Shoes from Adidas, the page shows up the another adidas products. So i have this code:

http://codepad.org/pO8XF0OI (Dont Know how to write code here)

Is actually working but only shows the products by the Category no by the Manufacturer.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

If you are using Vm2.x It will gives you full products under one manufacture.You can add or remove another tables based on your requirement.

```
                            $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
                            $sql = "SELECT N.product_name,M.virtuemart_product_id,MN.mf_name 
                            FROM jos_virtuemart_product_manufacturers AS M 
                            LEFT JOIN jos_virtuemart_products AS P ON M.virtuemart_product_id = P.virtuemart_product_id
                            LEFT JOIN jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb  AS N ON N.virtuemart_product_id = M.virtuemart_product_id
                            LEFT JOIN jos_virtuemart_manufacturers_en_gb AS MN ON MN.virtuemart_manufacturer_id = M.virtuemart_manufacturer_id
                            WHERE M.virtuemart_manufacturer_id = '$manufature_id'";
                            $db->setQuery($sql);
                            $db->query();
                            $res = $db->loadAssocList();
                            echo "<pre/>";
                            print_r($res);
```

Hope this may help...

Answer (score 0):

Is done, here is the code:

```
<?php
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $manufacturer = $this->product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id;
    $sql = "SELECT N.product_name,I.virtuemart_media_id,M.virtuemart_product_id,MN.mf_name 
    FROM h3ls8_virtuemart_product_manufacturers AS M 
    LEFT JOIN h3ls8_virtuemart_products AS P ON M.virtuemart_product_id = P.virtuemart_product_id
    LEFT JOIN h3ls8_virtuemart_products_es_es  AS N ON N.virtuemart_product_id = M.virtuemart_product_id
    LEFT JOIN h3ls8_virtuemart_product_medias  AS I ON M.virtuemart_product_id = I.virtuemart_product_id
    LEFT JOIN h3ls8_virtuemart_manufacturers_es_es AS MN ON MN.virtuemart_manufacturer_id = M.virtuemart_manufacturer_id
    WHERE M.virtuemart_manufacturer_id = '$manufacturer'"; // h3ls8_ is your table Prefix
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $db->query();
    /* $res = $db->loadAssocList(); //This Load the info as a List */
    $prod = $db->loadObjectList(); // This Load the info as a group of objects for loading it.

    JRequest::setVar('virtuemart_manufacturer_id',$this->product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id,'GET');
    $productModel = VmModel::getModel('product');

    if ($this->product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id !=0 ) {
        $products = $prod;
        $productModel->addImages($products);
        $this->assignRef('products', $products);
    }
    // Show Products
    if (!empty($products)) { ?>
        <div class="seven columns obras">
            <h5> Obras </h5>
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                // Start the Output
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                // Show Products
                ?>
                <div class="four columns mobile-two end producto">
                    <div class="imagen">
                        <!-- <?php //if ($product->product_special == 1) { ?>
                        <div class="oferta">
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <?php}?> *** If you wanna add some especial icon to a Special product uncommnent this *** -->  
                        <?php 
                            echo JHTML::_('link', JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id='.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'&virtuemart_category_id='.$product->virtuemart_category_id),$product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="catImage"',false));
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end of product -->
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jobin Jose, Great job dude.